# Vagrant reverse port forwarding?

Tags: vagrant, portforwarding

I'm working on a web services architecture. I've got some software that I need to run on the native host machine, not in Vagrant. But I'd like to run some client services on the guest.

Vagrant's `config.vm.forwarded_port` parameter will open a port on the host and send the data to the guest. But how can I open a port on the guest and send the data to the host? (It's still port forwarding, but in the reverse direction.)

Comment: Since Vagrant is using SSH it is theoretically possible and the [Ruby SSH implementation gem](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) supports this but never saw anything like this in the Vagrant docu.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19933550/1157054

Answer (score 142, accepted):

When you run `vagrant ssh`, it's actually using this underlying command:

`ssh -p 2222 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1`

SSH supports forwarding ports in the direction you want with the `-R guestport:host:hostport` option. So, if you wanted to connect to port `12345` on the guest and have it forwarded to `localhost:80`, you would use this command:

`ssh -p 2222 -R 12345:localhost:80 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=ERROR -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1`

As Eero correctly comments, you can also use the command `vagrant ssh -- -R 12345:localhost:80`, which has the same effect in a much more concise command.

Comment: and you can run this more simply using `vagrant ssh -- -R 12345:localhost:80`  This follows the ssh option syntax **-R** _[bind_address:]port:host:hostport_, where the first number is the port number to listen on inside the guest machine, and the last two are the service address as visible from the host machine.

Comment: As far as I understand that reverse forwarding only works in the corresponding ssh shell. I think Dan Fabulich wanted a solution without the need to ssh into the vm.

Comment: @Alp I believe it's a port available to the whole system, not just available to the ssh process. Works fine for me!

Comment: For those who use PuTTy, the SSH/Tunnels section of the configuration gui allows both Remote port forwarding (hence the -R in the command) or Local port forwarding (-L in the command line)

Comment: Or something accounting for vagrant's potentially differente config if you have multiple vagrant setup: `vagrant ssh-config | ssh -F /dev/stdin $BOX -R $PORT_VM:localhost:$PORT -N`

Comment: Thanks guy for you saving my day !!

Answer (score 107):

In the book `Vagrant: Up and Running` (Pub. date: June 12, 2013), written by the creator of Vagrant, he mentioned that it is not possible for guest machine to access services running on the host machine.

Instead of using `Forwarded Ports`, you could set up a private network using `Host-Only Networks`.

- Pros of using `Host-Only Networks` over `Forwarded Ports`

  1. Guest machines may access the services running on host machine

     This feature would solve your problem.
  2. Guest machines may access the services running on other guest machine

     This feature is very useful to separate services onto multiple machines to more accurately mimic a production environment.
  3. Secure

     Outside machines have no ways to access the services running on the guest machines
  4. Less work

     No need to configure every single `Forwarded Port`

---

- How to configure `Host-Only Networks`

  `config.vm.network :"hostonly", "192.168.0.0"`          # Vagrant Version #1

  `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.0"` # Vagrant Version #2

  Having this line in your `Vagrantfile` will instruct vagrant to create a private network that has a static IP address: `192.168.0.0`

  The IP address of the host is always the same IP address but with the final octet as a 1. In the preceding example, the host machine would have the IP address `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: In the same vein (also from `Vagrant: Up and Running`), you could set up a bridged network. On a bridged network, other machines in your local network can access your virtual machine, and vice versa. But since the IP address is assigned via DHCP, you'd have to `ifconfig` in the virtual machine to find its IP address.

Comment: The fact that when you setup config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.4" means that the guest will access the host by going to "192.168.50.1" is the key bit of information here. I cannot find that little tidbit documented anywhere.

Comment: I found using the answers address of `192.168.0.0` didn't work - curling / pinging the host machine was resulting in connection t/o's. Using @Nucleon's address (consistent with the [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) on the topic) worked as advertised.

Comment: @markdsievers, the last sentence of the answer actually states if you want to access the host machine from VM, the IP address is 192.168.0.1.  It seems that Nucleon does agree with the answer.  Anyway, I am glad your problem is resolved.

Comment: @Mingyu No - using your configuration line `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.0"` and curling / pinging the host on `192.168.0.1` was resulting in connection time outs. Configuring the network to be `192.168.50.4` resolved it ie host available at `192.168.50.1`.

Comment: "192.168.0.0" is not a good example, x.x.x.0 normally is for broadcast ing

Comment: For windows at least, the host adapter (192.168.x.1) is going to have the firewall deployed.  This can make it tricky to reach services on the host machine, or could require extra hostside configuration (which I try to avoid as much as possible since well I'm using Vagrant to push that stuff to VMs).

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman I'd amend that to say the host *may* have a firewall deployed; I don't see the issue with possible additional host configuration to use the VMs.

Comment: The `ip` command is very helpful with debugging/configuring networking on linux - it's well worth learning!
For example `ip l` will show all NICs, `ip a` shows all assigned addresses/masks and `ip r` will show all routing (default route will be via router which in this case must be the host computer)

Comment: @Nucleon Help me to understand how the guest will access the host by going to "192.168.50.1"?

Answer (score 83):

You can access ports on the host machine through the default gateway inside the guest OS. (Which typically has an IP of `10.0.2.2`.)

For example, if you have a webserver running on port 8000 on your host machine...

```
echo 'Hello, guest!' > hello
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

You can access it from inside the Vagrant VM at `10.0.2.2:8000` (provided `10.0.2.2` is the ip of the guest's default gateway):

```
vagrant ssh
curl http://10.0.2.2:8000/hello # Outputs: Hello, guest!
```

To find the IP of the default gateway inside the guest OS, run `netstat -rn` (or `ipconfig` on a Windows guest) and look for the row with a destination IP of `0.0.0.0` (or the field labeled "Default Gateway" on Windows):

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

You can extract this IP programmatically with `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f2`.

<sub>Sources: [How to connect with host PostgreSQL from vagrant virtualbox machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19933550/1157054); [Connect to the host machine from a VirtualBox guest OS?](https://superuser.com/q/310697/83682)</sub>

Comment: I like this solution a lot too because it just worked without even stopping my current vagrant ssh session. Thanks!

Comment: Bravo ! this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Excellent! `ifconfig` and `ip address` weren't getting me what I needed, but `netstat -rn` did.

Answer (score 10):

Add following to your `~/.ssh/config` on the host machine:

```
Host 127.0.0.1
RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698
```

It lets you access a service on host machine port 52698 from Vagrant, as long as you logged in via `vagrant ssh`.

You can confirm it works by running `netstat -lt` on vagrant VM and taking a note on the following lines:

```
tcp      0    0 localhost:52698         *:*                 LISTEN
tcp6     0    0 ip6-localhost:52698     [::]:*              LISTEN
```

Comment: +1 This was a huge help to me. I added the given text replacing with port 5037 to allow my vagrant box to be able to listen to the android emulator running on my host box.

Answer (score 2):

I can access services running on my host machine via its local IP address (not its loopback address). I tested by creating an http server on port 80 (and then on port 987) and `curl`ing 197.45.0.10:80 and 197.45.0.10:987 (actual ip address changed to protect the innocent). It worked both times, and I don't have any special vagrant configuration (no public_network, no forwarded_port) and while I do have some ports forwarded via PuTTY, I don't have ports 80 and 987 forwarded. So maybe try using the host machine's local or public IP address.

And if you want to access (ssh into) one guest vagrant instance from another, you can enable `public_network` as well as forwarding from port 22 in the `Vagrantfile` like this:

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2200
```

Then as long as that port is open (ie do some more port forwarding in your router config) you can access that machine from anywhere, even the outside world.