# How to connect with host PostgreSQL from vagrant virtualbox machine

Tags: postgresql, networking, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a VirtualBox machine running Ubuntu 12.04 in a Mac OS X host machine. In my host machine (Mac OS X), I have PostgreSQL installed. I would like to connect to this PostgreSQL server **from** my Ubuntu virtual machine (I know normally it's the opposite way).

I guess I should configure some networking parameters in VirtualBox itself. All I get from [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) is I need to assign my vm a static IP to use a private network. But once created, how do I reach my host from my guest?

I didn't find anything like that in vagrant docs. So, there's probably a good reason for that. Does it make sense? I don't want to duplicate PostgreSQL installation. Just use my current existent one.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can reach your host from your guest by using the default gateway on your VM.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/310745/157900) for an explanation.

By running `netstat -rn` you can get the default gateway and then use that ip address in your config file of your application.

Running `netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10` should give you the correct ip address. (only tested this on my machine)

Comment: That command works for me too
(guest == ubuntu/trusty64).  
Could connect to host mysql & ssh services (at least).

Comment: This doesn't work with the VMWare Ubuntu machines, unfortunately. I get a IP address but can't send connections through it, they're stuck in SYN_SENT.

Answer (score 36):

Easy way - simply use this "magic" IP from inside of vagrant without any additional configurations:

`10.0.2.2`

Don't know if it's always static, though for me works and it's very convenient - I can use laptop at home, from office - having assigned different IPs to me by routers, but my VMs know the "trusty name" of their master

Comment: I cannot explain why this is the default or how to customize it either, but I can confirm that on several of my machines I have this `ip route` entry:
`10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100`
Meaning it seems to give the VM itself the address 10.0.2.15. Why .2 and .15 I don't know but just backing this up that Vagrant seems to be doing this automatically.

Comment: I think it's virtualbox default nat and network configuration doing this

Comment: If someone wants to run the application from host as well as guest then we can use ipv4 address as database host.