# Connect to Host MySQL Server on Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant

It's possible to connect to the Host's MySQL Server inside a Vagrant box? I'm running a RoR vagrant box, but I need to connect to the host database server.

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the MySQL server trough a client? If that's the case you could simply SSH into (Vagrant/Vagrant) it. This way you don't have to mess with all kinds of settings just to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

There are two thread one on stack overflow and another on superuser that might help you out with doing this. Links below.

[How to connect with host PostgreSQL from vagrant virtualbox machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933550/how-to-connect-with-host-postgresql-from-vagrant-virtualbox-machine)

https://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os/310745#310745

It is possible to do what you are trying to achieve if you get your settings correct.