# Vagrant forward port on host to guest

Tags: networking, vagrant

I'd like to forward port 3306 (MySQL) on my local machine to a Vagrant guest.

I know that there is a way to forward from *guest* to *host*, but is there a way to forward from *host* to *guest*? I'm running Vagrant 1.5.4 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can reach the host from the default gateway IP in use by the VM.  Check out this other question that was answered a while back:

[How to connect with host PostgreSQL from vagrant virtualbox machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933550/how-to-connect-with-host-postgresql-from-vagrant-virtualbox-machine)

The script listed there to find the gateway worked for me.