# Connect to MySQL in windows from Vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant, mysql-workbench

I have created a database in my Windows machine. How to connect to this database from vagrant instance running on the same machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect with host PostgreSQL from vagrant virtualbox machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933550/how-to-connect-with-host-postgresql-from-vagrant-virtualbox-machine)

Comment: Not really a dup, as netstat does not work on windows!