# Access elasticsearch from vagrant

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant

Hi I've been trying almost everything to access my elasticsearch database from my vagrant VM. In this forum there are plenty of threads but none of them seems to work, that's why I'm posting.

The thing is that if I type: curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:9200  outside of vagrant I'll get the content of my elastisearch localhost.

Inside of vagrant I connect to my mongodb databases through:

```
mongo 10.0.2.2:27017
```

Therefore, and following one of these answers:

[Vagrant reverse port forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244601/vagrant-reverse-port-forwarding)

I expected that by changing this:

```
vagrant ssh -- -R 12345:localhost:80
```

into this:

```
vagrant ssh -- -R 12345:10.0.2.2:9200
```

I would be able to access my elasticsearch from vagrant if I typed:

```
curl -X GET http://10.0.2.2:9200
```

but I'm not getting anything...

This is the content of my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # config.vm.box = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
  config.vm.box = "xenial-amd64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box"
  config.vm.hostname = "proxy"


  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.90.103"



  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provisions/shell/bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure your vagrant-elasticsearch is listening on all network interfaces (not only localhost)

Edit the file `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and change a few things

```
network.bind_host: 0
network.host: 0.0.0.0

# I do that for cors
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/.*/
```

Make sure to restart elasticsearch after the changes. This will allow you to access your vagrant-elasticsearch from your host machine.

I think the easiest to work with is to set a static IP to your VM, you can edit your Vagrantfile and have (just an example of IP address)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.90.103"
  ...
end
```

then you can easily access elasticsearch using http://192.168.90.103:9200

Comment: I'm getting this error: /sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null

THis is because of the config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.90.103" line. If I remove it I won't get any errors but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: hum ... can you post your Vagrantfile and provide vagrant version you use

Comment: ok and vagrant version ? are you on the latest 1.9.x version ?

Comment: vagrant 1.8.x had such [issues](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7155) so upgrading will help you

Comment: I updated it, I don't get the error thanks to the newest version BUT running: curl -X GET http://192.168.90.103:9200  inside of vagrant doesn't retrieve anything... :(

Comment: hum ... can you confirm with the new setup that `curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:9200` inside the VM works well ? does it work from the host ?

Comment: @ApoorvNag thats the first thing mentioned in the answer